# Problems with generating xsd file because ref to a element in another schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have some problems generating a xsd file from a schema because it is ref to a element in another schema. Any of you know how to work around this? here is the schema that i am trying to make a xsd from.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="urn:ean.ucc:2" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:ean.ucc:2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import />
  <xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="entityIdentification" />
        <xs:element name="transaction">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="entityIdentification" />
              <xs:element ref="command" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="documentCommand">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="documentCommandHeader" />
        <xs:element ref="documentCommandOperand" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see it ref to alot of other elements. The way i created this schema was by using the tool in vs2013 for creating schemas from XML files.

Hope som of you know how to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on and understand how XML namespaces work and how they are relevant to the relationship between two schemas, when one them is using types from the other one.

[This article](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx) is an excelent starting point for this understanding; although the tool used is pay-for, I am not promoting or affiliated in any way.

The relevant bits:

> CommonTypes.xsd
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
> <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes" 
>            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>            elementFormDefault="qualified">
>
>   <xs:complexType name="AddressType">
>     <xs:sequence>
>       <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string" />
>       <xs:element name="Line2" type="xs:string" />
>     </xs:sequence>
>   </xs:complexType>
>
>   <xs:simpleType name="PriceType">
>     <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
>       <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
>     </xs:restriction>
>   </xs:simpleType>
>
>   <xs:simpleType name="PaymentMethodType">
>     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
>       <xs:enumeration value="VISA" />
>       <xs:enumeration value="MasterCard" />
>       <xs:enumeration value="Cash" />
>       <xs:enumeration value="Amex" />
>     </xs:restriction>
>   </xs:simpleType>
> </xs:schema>
> ```
>
> CustomerTypes.xsd
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
> <xs:schema     xmlns:cmn="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes" 
>                targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CustomerTypes" 
>                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>                elementFormDefault="qualified">
>     <xs:import schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd" 
>                namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes"/>
>   <xs:complexType name="CustomerType">
>     <xs:sequence>
>       <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
>       <xs:element name="DeliveryAddress" type="cmn:AddressType" />
>       <xs:element name="BillingAddress" type="cmn:AddressType" />
>     </xs:sequence>
>   </xs:complexType>
> </xs:schema>
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Tom Redfern this is a nice guide.